# file_put_contents saving different timestamp to server

Tags: php, linux

I have setup an error logging for mysql queries with php.

```
 $line = date('d-m-Y H:i:s') . " - " . $sql .  mysqli_error($conn);
 file_put_contents('../errorlog.log', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

problem is that the time inserted is 8 hours from the time set on my server.

```
date -u
```

from my linux machine does show the correct time. currently 06:30 however the above php displays 16:32. so there is an 8 hour difference and not sure how I could correct this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `date_default_timezone_get()` show?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `php.ini` setting called `date.timezone`, where you can set the default timezone for PHP. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

On script level you can control this using the [`date_default_timezone_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function.

List of supported timezones: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: I have done this and it has changed the time however, the time is now 2 hours behind. 4:45am when local is 6:45am. Australia/Melbourne is currently in daylight savings, so having it 1 hour behind is fine but very strange that it is behind by 2.